# Rails form remove has many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I remove a has many relationship via an input tag in rails?

I have a model named invoice.

```
has_many :expenses
```

I am trying this to remove all associated models for the invoice:

```
input name="invoice[expense_ids][]" value=""
```

But it seems not to work. What is the correct way for the input tag to have the params in the correct format for the update_attributes function in the update action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how i do it is in the controller

```
invoice.expense_ids = [] if invoice.persisted?
invoice.update_attributes(params[:invoice])
```

which will basically remove any expense associations before updating the record, so existing ones will be added back or it will be blank if there are none passed in.

the longer way to do it is to basically remove any that are no longer in the array

```
ids = invoice.expense_ids
ids = ids.keep_if{|i|, params[:invoice][:expense_ids].include?(i)}
invoice.expense_ids = ids
```

Comment: Thanks works perfect + good idea. Why do you use the invoice.persisted? Records to be updated are usually already persisted, or?

Comment: yeah thats my bad i usually use the same controller for update/create (dry principals i guess)

Comment: Do you have an example for such a controller? I would be very interested in reading that code. Thanks.

Comment: i don't have any OSS solutions but here is my contrived version https://gist.github.com/j-mcnally/5259239

Comment: Another note is we generally don't do much in controllers, as most things are handled in model hooks, and with accepts_nested_attributes for alot of relationship based things.